# Is it possible to turn rockets without fuel just like in KSP

Tags: rockets, kerbal-space-program, turning

When playing KSP if you click a Key (A,S,D,W) then the rocket turns without using fuel. I thought that a rocket needed RCS to turn. Is it even possible to turn a rocket in space without using any fuel?

Comment: Perhaps worth noting that while the principle is real, reaction wheels in KSP are unrealistically powerful by a factor of about 100 - this is done for the sake of the game so you don't have to wait several minutes/hours to reorient your craft.

Comment: Have a read through [Intuition as to why the orientation (of a 3D object) is not a conserved quantity?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/166966/intuition-as-to-why-the-orientation-of-a-3d-object-is-not-a-conserved-quantity)

Comment: It's worth pointing out KSP parts really do include (unrealistically powerful) reaction wheels - it's not just out-of-universe magic plot torque. I think all the manned capsules include reaction wheels, so you'd be forgiven for thinking all spacecraft have them magically.

Comment: Can you define "without fuel", please? Why is it not obvious that although gizmoes such as gyroscopes need no fuel to wind down, winding them up did consume fuel?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

> Is it even possible to turn a rocket in space without using any fuel?

That's the primary reason reaction wheels, control moment gyros, magnetic torquers, etc. (I'm sure I'm missing some) were invented. They don't need propellant. The ones I cited do need electrical power, but not propellant.

Eventually, reaction wheels and control moment gyros do become saturated, in which case propellant is needed to desaturate them.

Comment: How do those things work. Do you just have a wheel spinning in a direction and the rocket goes into the other?

Comment: @TheRocketfan That's how reaction wheels work. Control moment gyros are a different beast. They spin rapidly. You push on them in a direction orthogonal to the spin axis, and the result is a torque normal to both the spin axis and the push axis. Magnetic torquers (aka magnetorquers) have no moving parts. They use the Earth's magnetic field to help them turn.

Comment: Thanks for that explanation. Do the Magnetic torquers only work while in LEO?

Comment: @TheRocketfan Pretty much, primarily because of the $1/R^3$ drop off in the strength in the Earth's magnetic field.

Comment: Thank you for that. That is a good simple explanation. I accept it!

Comment: @TheRocketfan for an illustration of how CMGs work, see the classic physics lecture demo https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5cRb0xvPJ2M

Comment: @TheRocketfan, note that KSP reaction wheels are *massively* overpowered compared to real-world reaction wheels.  Reaction wheels in the real world tend to produce speeds on the order of rotations per hour, not rotations per second.

Comment: Magnetic torques also work in some Jupiter orbits

Comment: @OscarSmith I'd assume they would also work around other gas giants, which also have significant magnetic fields?

Comment: The basic idea of a Reaction Wheel is that it's the change in relative velocity that imparts forces on the overall spacecraft. So if you have a big spinning wheel with a lot of mass whirling around at a steady rate, the rocket won't rotate. But as soon as you start trying to slow it down, you're essentially pulling the craft with the inertia of the wheel. This slows the wheel, but it also turns the craft too. Eventually the wheel will be spinning at the same rate as the ship in which case you need to spin it up again, but you'll need to use fuel to stop the ship spinning while you do that.

Comment: As for saturation, for long term and slow moving stuff one technical way to "desaturate" the other than via propulsion is by using the magnetic field as drag source.